# CakePHP 1.3 Routing problem

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

It can't correct route from the following:

```
Router::connect('/ctl/act/subact/:mode/:sort'       
, array('controller' => 'ctl', 'action' => 'act_subact',
'mode' => null , 'sort' => null));
```

--

```
$html->link('go',array('controller'=>'ctl','action'=>'act_subact'))
```

--

```
<a href="/ctl/act_subact/">go</a>
```

How can I do?
Env:CakePHP 1.3.6 php5.2.5 on apache2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Route `/ctl/act/subact/:mode/:sort` means that there must be a `:mode` and `:sort` parameter. This route would not match the URL `/ctl/act/subact/`. If there are optional parameters, you need to denote those with an asterisk: `/ctl/act/subact/*`. This route would match the URLs `/ctl/act/subact/`, `/ctl/act/subact/foo` and `/ctl/act/subact/foo/bar`.

If you need these optional parameters as named parameters, you'll need to create several routes for each possible "length":

```
Router::connect('/ctl/act/subact/:mode/:sort', array('controller' => 'ctl', 'action' => 'act_subact', 'mode' => null, 'sort' => null));
Router::connect('/ctl/act/subact/:mode', array('controller' => 'ctl', 'action' => 'act_subact', 'mode' => null));
Router::connect('/ctl/act/subact/', array('controller' => 'ctl', 'action' => 'act_subact'));
```